# Converting Ruby to C#

Tags: c#, ruby

how do I write this in c# ?
Ruby Code:

```
Time.now.gmtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

I've tried finding on the web a converter, but failed.

Comment: -1 for lack of [searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

or

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: use `UtcNow` for this to be correct, the original code specifies that it is in [GMT](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html) which is not Utc but I suspect that's what they intended.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");